# WP_User_Query. Whats wrong with 'relation' => 'OR'

Tags: query, users

I want all the users who meet either Condition1 **OR** Condition2. Sort by last_name.

If I take condition1 **AND** condition2 ('relation' => 'AND'), the query is OK.
If I take 'relation' => 'OR', I get all records and unsorted. 
What is wrong?

```
    $args = array(
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'OR', 
        0 => array(
            'key'       => 'user_thema1',
            'value'     => $kate_name,
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        1 => array(
            'key'     => 'user_thema2',
            'value'   => $kate_name,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'      => 'last_name',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value'
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Probably just a typo, but shouldn't it be  $args = array(

Comment: And the `0=>array(` is another typo error. I'm surprised you get something with that code other than PHP syntax errors.

Comment: Well, I have written my code wrong. Excuse me! I have modified the code. In the original, it looks like this. I applied to the code for "Multiple custom user fields handling" oriented [http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query]. Please check again at the code. What is wrong? Many Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It was a bug in Wordpress. Please see [this track ticket #21581](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21581) for details.